# Text align right distinctly without using position:relative

Tags: html, css

I have a table and I want all the ab's to line up (ie I want to shift some columns 2 characters left) as shown below where I used non-breaking-spaces (why do I need four?)
But I want to achieve this using only classes and if necessary, spans. I tried using `margin-right` on an internal span, or `padding-right` on the `td`, but both seem to revert to `text-align: left`. I do not want to use `position:absolute`.

```css
td {
    text-align: right;
}

td .b {
    margin-right: 2em;
}

td.c {
    /*padding-right: 2em;*/
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>12ab34</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ab34</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ab34</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ab&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="a">12ab34</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="a">ab34</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="a">ab34</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="c"><span class="b">ab</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"...I used non-breaking-spaces (why do I need four?)"*

A ***n**on-**b**reaking **sp**ace* width is roughly 25% of an `em`. So going off of the first `<table>` you can use a right margin of 1em (see **Figure I**).

**Figure I**

```
.b {margin-right: 1em}
```

Another way is to use spacing like you did with `&nbsp;` but with an `em` space as content of an `::after` pseudo-class. (see **Figure II**)

**Figure II**

```
.d::after {
  content: '\002003';
}
```

```css
td {
  text-align: right
}

td .b {
  margin-right: 1em;
}

td.c {
  /*padding-right: 2em;*/
}

.d::after {
  content: '\002003';
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>12ab34</td></tr>
  <tr><td>ab34</td></tr>
  <tr><td>ab34</td></tr>
  <tr><td>ab&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>  
</table><br>

<table>
  <tr><td><span class="a">12ab34</span></td></tr>
  <tr><td><span class="a">ab34</span></td></tr>
  <tr><td><span class="a">ab34</span></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="c"><span class="b">ab</span></td></tr>  
</table><br>

<table>
  <tr><td>12ab34</td></tr>
  <tr><td>ab34</td></tr>
  <tr><td>ab34</td></tr>
  <tr><td class='d'>ab</td></tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: It takes 4 nbsp to make 1em. I never said 1em is two characters wide, I said, *"A non-breaking space width is roughly 25% of an em. "*